# Read and Write JQuery Statements in One Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery statement in a loop. `#MainContent_gvDemographic` and `#tblFreez` are two tables in a page.

```
$("#MainContent_gvDemographic").find(str)
                               .css("height", $("#tblFreez")
                               .find(str)
                               .css("height"))
```

When there are many steps in the loop, it takes a very long time to complete. To fix the problem, I then use two loops, one for reading the height of $("#tblFreez").find(str), the other for writing the height into `$("#MainContent_gvDemographic").find(str)`, and use an array to carry the height data between the two loops. It becomes much faster now. Does anyone know why the two solutions have such big difference in performance? The computational complexity looks the same to me.

All right, here are the two complete version.
Original:

```
function FixHeight() {
 var rowCount = $('#tblFreez tr').length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var str = "";

            if ($.browser.msie) {
                str = "tr:eq(" + i + ") td";
            }
            else {
                str = "tr:eq(" + i + ")";
            }        
           $("#MainContent_gvDemographic").find(str).css("height", $("#tblFreez").find(str).css("height"));               
        }
```

}

New:

```
function FixHeight() {
        var rowCount = $('#tblFreez tr').length;
        var hei = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var str = "";
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                str = "tr:eq(" + i + ") td";
            }
            else {
                str = "tr:eq(" + i + ")";
            }
            hei[i] = $("#tblFreez").find(str).css("height");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var str = "";

            if ($.browser.msie) {
                str = "tr:eq(" + i + ") td";
            }
            else {
                str = "tr:eq(" + i + ")";
            }

            $("#MainContent_gvDemographic").find(str).css("height", hei[i]);
        }
```

}

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you showed the code for each version.

Comment: Why would you have that statement in a loop? It should go after the loop.

Comment: What are you iterating? Post the complete code so we can validate and suggest if there is a better way.

Comment: You should start by defining jquery elements outside the loop, first I see is $("#tblFreez"). Searching for an element in the DOM is an expensive operation

Comment: @gpasci agreed, but back to the initial question: it occurs in both versions.

Comment: You might want to **Bold** the text **Does anyone know why the two solutions have such big difference in performance?** - Since so many responses seem to be ignoring that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM operations are usually the expensive operations.

Your first version has heavy DOM operation, but your second version has the count. It looks like load vs number.

Ideally, your first version should be faster as it is just one loop and the number of iteration is half than the second version.. but it is not always the case.

Assume your memory is like 1000M in which 300M can be garbage collected meaning it can be cleaned up. So the Operating systems memory model would call the garbage collector whenever your memory gets closer to 1000M. With those conditions in mind, lets say in your first version, every 5 iterate takes 1000M, which would end up calling garbage collector to clean up or free up resources for next iteration. So if you end up running for 100 iteration which is equals to 100 iteration + 20 times GC processing.

In your second case, assume it take 50 iteration to fill up 1000M, so you would end up calling 4 time GC processing which is basically 20 vs 4 times calling some other process inbetween each of your iterate.

Above is just a speculation and the actual memory modules are much smarter than what I have explained, but that is just to give an idea of load vs numbers.

Anyways..Try below code and see if it fixes your problem,

**Setting height at TR level**

```
var fTable = document.getElementById('#tblFreez');
$("#MainContent_gvDemographic tr").each(function(ridx) {          
      $(this).height($(fTable.rows[ridx]).height());
});
```

**Setting height at TD level**

```
var fTable = document.getElementById('#tblFreez');
$("#MainContent_gvDemographic tr").each(function(ridx) {
      $(this).find('td').each(function (cidx) {
          $(this).height($(fTable.rows[ridx].cols[cidx]).height());
     });
});
```

Comment: An interesting speculation. I was speculating that the difference might more generally be "optimisation". And I wouldn't be surprised if different browsers with different javascript execution engines would offer different results. Some configurations, for example, might even get through the original implementation faster? Any willing participants could, for example, scour the code of open source V8 JS engine (assuming it exhibits the issue) - https://code.google.com/p/v8/ - PS - I am **not** volunteering to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use only **one** loop and not `for` but jQuery `.each()`. I haven't tested code below, but should work.

```
function FixHeight() {
    var $MainContent = $("#MainContent_gvDemographic");
    var $tblFreezRows = $("#tblFreez tr");

    var hei, $row;
    $tblFreezRows.each(function(index, elem){
        $row = $(this);

        if ($.browser.msie) {
            hei = $row.find('td').css("height");
            $MainContent.find("tr:eq(" + index + ") td").css("height", hei);
        }
        else {
            hei = $row.css("height");
            $MainContent.find("tr:eq(" + index + ")").css("height", hei);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try detaching the elements before you alter/search them. Then re-append them. DOM-operations are costly.